# Enabling feature flags in Ember AppKit app at runtime

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'm using EAK and a canary build of Ember - this was the same with beta & canaray builds from emberjs.com as well as alexpenner's build at http://ember.alexspeller.com/ember-latest.js

So Ember should of course be managed by bower. I am trying to use the 'query-params' feature in EAK, and per the ember guide (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) placed the line

```
Ember.FEATURES["query-params"] = true;
```

directly before the App.create line in app.js

Inside the relevant route,

```
renderTemplate:  function( controller, context, queryParams ) {
    console.log(queryParams);
}
```

Would always log undefined, until I added the above features line to the actual Ember source (in the vendor folder :/ ). For instance, right after the features hash is defined in ember.js, adding `Ember.feature["query-params"] = true` and refreshing would yield the proper params object in the console.

This indicates to me that the feature is working properly in all respects (i.e. the object is being accessed correctly in the app), but I would like to be able to enable the flag in a reasonable place such as app.js

Any idea why it would not work to enable the flag above the app.create line? Is there a different way to approach this in EAK?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your question?

Comment: It ended up working in a later version of Ember

Answer (score 2):

You should try putting your environment variables in [config/environment.js](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/blob/master/config/environment.js).

I believe that is the EAK approach.